# Windows.Foundation.Rect Rounding bounds for some values in uwp

Tags: windows, uwp

When I give some values(for example, 130016848) , Windows.Foundation.Rect rounds  Unit Place Digit to near 0 or to 8.

say, consider below as my Values that i gave for a rect
Rect range = new Rect(0, 130016845,5312,2988);

Where as Rect rounded up my values to
range.X = 0,range.Y=130016848, range.width = 5312, range.height=2988.

Similarly when Rect range = new Rect(0, 130016843,5312,  2988);
i got range.X = 0,range.Y=130016840, range.width = 5312, range.height=2988.

Comment: It seems that the number out of the significant digits of float will be rounded bounds. Tried a value like 1016845, it shows correct value.

Comment: The members of Rect are `float`, and 130016843 is to big to be represented as `float` exactly.